# Timing Out a Command Line Execution in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm building a PS program to execute several java programs. Some programs may take over the maximum amount of time that I would like to allow. If this happens, I would like to stop the execution of them and continue forward. So far I've used this:

```
$j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {java -jar .\Tournament.jar Students.csv 7777}
Wait-Job $j -Timeout 10 | out-null
if($j.State -eq "Completed"){ "Done!" } 
elseif($j.State -eq "Running"){"Program took longer than the max limit."}
Remove-Job -force $j
```

It seems to not recognize that the jar file is still running, as it flags the "Completed" condition as true. The jar file should take at least 70 seconds to execute. Also, it does seem to shut down the jar execution, because the jar never creates it's output file.

**Update 11/30/2015**

Replaced the above code with this and it seems to work:

```
$p = Start-Process java -ArgumentList '-jar', '.\Tournament.jar', 'Students.csv', '7777' -RedirectStandardError '.\console.err' -NoNewWindow -passthru
if(! $p.WaitForExit(10000)){
    "Program took longer than max time"
    $p.kill()
}
```

Any additional comments would be appreciated.

Comment: why is the last line necessary [timeout](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849735.aspx) should stop the process. can you run a while while($j.State -ne "Completed"){} to show how long it will run for? can you list .ChildJobs while it's running.

Comment: I implemented `while($j.State -ne "Completed"){}` and it seems to pause for about 5 seconds and then it continues. It seems like, once the command line executes the command and passes everything to java, the PS moves on with the script. As for ChildJobs, it shows the java -jar command, but it also list the state as Completed.

Comment: and the jar program has no error logging or verbose options? Are there any childjobs running ?

Comment: I found some additional information when looking for error logging information. I think I have it working now. I'll display the code above.